# Mint sugar wine

Tags: ingredients, wine

I'm planning on making sugar wine. I want to improve the flavor by adding mint but I don't know where I can get three cups of fresh mint. If I use mint extract, or mint oil will it do the same thing?

Comment: Mint extract probably uses some form of alcohol as a solvent.  I would not add it until after fermentation is complete.

Comment: did I get the question right?  you don't know where to get fresh mint?

Answer (score 6):

Mint extract and mint oil won't do the same thing as leaves, not exactly. The flavor is different. If you infuse it with mint leaves, the flavor can have a more "leafy" or herbal quality, not necessarily a good thing. And infusions can change the color of your liquor, which if you're drinking it straight is not ideal. For these reasons, I'd use extract. It's also cheaper than oil, more shelf stable, and it's less concentrated which makes it easier to adjust how minty your hooch is. Just add it at the end when the kilju is finished and filtered. You can consider using peppermint extract instead of mint, which is usually a combination of peppermint and spearmint. And you might want to add a little simple syrup too.

Comment: Absolutely right. The leaves will turn your concoction brown. Anecdotal, but I've done this before. Although the taste isn't bad.